# Ionic Run Android: Splashscreen and icon reverting to cordova default icons

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

When doing a "ionic run android" with my Android devices, the splashscreen and icon come up as the cordova defaults, not the ones I made. I've already run "ionic resources","ionic resources --splash and icon" and the images seem to have built correctly, since I checked platforms/android/res and they are there. I removed and readded the android platform, also didn't help.

My Cordova CLI version is 6.4.0. I read that downgrading to 6.3.1 could help, but doing this gave me this error:
A problem occured configuring root project 'android'.

> failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk

Android 23 is installed in my sdk. I uninstalled cordova and ionic and then reinstalled them, the same issue still appeared. I had to go back to 6.4.0 to get rid of the error, but then I'm back again stuck with the same cordova default splash and icon.

Comment: did you also try the command `prepare android`, or even `rm android` then `add android` again?

Comment: yes removing and readding I've done many times, haven't tried prepare yet. Thanks

Comment: Have you runned `ionic build android`?

Comment: I recommend: `http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/setup/deploying/`

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it:

```
ionic platform remove android
ionic platform add android@6.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try this with argument for splash, make sure icon and splash screen match with proper size.

```
ionic resources --splash
```

and for Icon

```
 ionic resources --icon
```

and also update sdk api Level upto 24 because many plugins are only support in api level 24 only.